# Mudar e Salvar a Cor da linha do DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Quero mudar a cor da linha do `DataGridView` e até consigo.

Código:

```
private void btnativo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MudarCor();
}

public void MudarCor()
{
    dgvIngrediente.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    dgvIngrediente.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
}
}
```

Porém quando eu fecho meu formulário e abro ele de novo, as linhas do `DataGridView` voltam com a cor normal e não com a que eu alterei. Gostaria de saber como eu faço para salvar a cor e deixar ela permanente.

Comment: você tem que gravar essa cores de alteração na base de dados não vejo outra forma!

Comment: Pensei que houvesse outra maneira.

Comment: permanente ao meu ver seria base de dados, que todas as vezes teria um cor já escolhida por você, abriu o formulário lia o banco e pronto cor escolhida mostra... não vejo outra maneira...

Comment: Se voce já tiver um banco de dados para o sistema, é melhor usar mesmo o banco, caso contrario, voce pode usar um arquivo xml ou outro arquivo texto.
Estes seriam bem mais simples do que criar um banco de dados apenas para gravar uma configuração.

Comment: Enzo, Você já tentou usar o Attributes e dar uma class para o DataGridView? Desse modo a class permanecerá nele de qualquer maneira, a menos que dê refresh na página.